# Java "Variable Name" Can't be resolved, Error with Variable in IF Statement

Tags: java, variables, if-statement

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter up to 5 Tests:");
int test1 = scan.nextInt();
if (test1 > -1){
  int test2 = scan.nextInt();
} else {
  if (test2 > -1){
    int test3 = scan.nextInt();
  } else {
    if (test3 > -1){
      int test4 = scan.nextInt();
    } else {
      if (test4 > -1){
        int test5 = scan.nextInt();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get a compile error that "`test2` cannot be resolved to a variable," which happens for every variable except `test1`. I assume that it is because `test2` doesn't exist until we make it by entering a value. What can I do here to make Java happy?

Answer (score 5):

You are defining `test2` inside this block -

```
if (test1 > -1){
    int test2 = scan.nextInt();
}
```

so, you won't be able to access it outside. This is how Java works. Similar is true for `test3` and `test4` (would have been true for `test5` too if you would've accessed it outside its definition block).

To make the variables available to the entire method, you could do something like this -

```
public static void main (String str[]) throws IOException {

    int test1, test2, test3, test4, test5;

    // rest of your code;
}
```

To learn more about variable scope, take a [quick look](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/VariableScope.htm).

You may also like to initialize your variables with some initial value, as testing them directly without initialization in the `if` condition will lead you into trouble.

Comment: The only thing that I'd mention (and this tripped me up for a second) is that due to the way he has his if-else statements, some of the variables may not have been initialized, and will throw a compile-time exception.

Answer (score 0):

it is because test2,test3 and test4 are local variables.Make test2,test3 and test4 as global variables
test2,test3 and test4 are defined with in if blocks
Try with the following code

```
public static void main (String str[]) throws IOException {


          Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int test1=0,test2=0,test3=0,test4=0,test5=0;
          System.out.println("Enter up to 5 Tests:");
          test1 = scan.nextInt();
          if (test1 > -1){
          test2 = scan.nextInt();
          } else {
            if (test2 > -1){
          test3 = scan.nextInt();
          } else {
            if (test3 > -1){
          test4 = scan.nextInt();
          } else {
            if (test4 > -1){
          test5 = scan.nextInt();
            }}}}
```

Comment: The only thing that I'd mention (and this tripped me up for a second) is that due to the way he has his if-else statements, some of the variables may not have been initialized, and will throw a compile-time exception. Also, I hope that he doesn't need to use `test5` later in his code ;)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, test2, test3, etc. are declared in one scope, but after that scope closes, they are no longer available. As a fix (judging by what you're trying to do), I'd suggest declaring them at the beginning of the method as such:=declare the ints at the beginning of the method:

```
public static void main(String str[])
        throws IOException
{
    int test1 = -1, test2 = -1, test3 = -1, test4 = -1, test5 = -1;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter up to 5 Tests:");
    test1 = scan.nextInt();
    if(test1 > -1)
    {
        test2 = scan.nextInt();
    }
    else
    {
        if(test2 > -1)
        {
            test3 = scan.nextInt();
        }
        else
        {
            if(test3 > -1)
            {
                test4 = scan.nextInt();
            }
            else
            {
                if(test4 > -1)
                {
                    test5 = scan.nextInt();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Furthermore, it doesn't look like your method will do what you want it to; if `test1` is valid, it takes in test2, but finishes there. To that end, what you're probably wanting to do is this:

```
public static void main(String str[])
        throws IOException
{
    int test1 = -1, test2 = -1, test3 = -1, test4 = -1, test5 = -1;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter up to 5 Tests:");

    test1 = scan.nextInt();
    if(test1 > -1)
    {
        test2 = scan.nextInt();
    }
    if(test2 > -1)
    {
        test3 = scan.nextInt();
    }
    if(test3 > -1)
    {
        test4 = scan.nextInt();
    }
    if(test4 > -1)
    {
        test5 = scan.nextInt();
    }

    // Work with the tests.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `test2` is not visible to out side first if statement you will get this error. Define your variables such that they can access entire if else blocks.